# About split string

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, nodemcu, json

Sorry my English is poor.

I use nodemcu to get a json data.

By this `String alldata = client.readString();`

But it turn this:

```
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Server: nginx
  Date: Sat, 10 Aug 2019 04:53:16 GMT
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: 152
  Connection: keep-alive
  X-RateLimit-Limit-day: 20000
  X-RateLimit-Remaining-day: 19968
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Pragma: no-cache
  Expires: -1
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  X-Kong-Upstream-Latency: 23
  X-Kong-Proxy-Latency: 2
  Via: kong/0.14.1
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload

  [{"Direction":0,"EstimateTime":364,"StopStatus":0,"MessageType":0,"SrcUpdateTime":"2019-08-10T12:53:00+08:00","UpdateTime":"2019-08-10T12:53:05+08:00"}]
```

I need '364' to display on oled.

Is it possible to split it.Thanks!

Comment: yes it is possible to extract the value ... google `arduino parsing strings`

Comment: cut away the HTTP headers (until the empty line). use ArduinoJson library to parse the payload

Comment: Thanks I have solve it.